# How do i sort (swap) items inside an Immutable Map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, redux, immutable.js

I want to **swap items** inside an immutable list within a `Map`, 
example:

```
const Map = Immutable.fromJS({
    name:'lolo',
    ids:[3,4,5]
});
```

i am trying to use splice to do the swapping, also tried with `insert()` an Immutable method.

Lets say i want to swap from `[3, 4, 5]` to `[3, 5, 4]`, i am truing something like this:

`list.set('ids', list.get('ids').splice(2, 0, list.get('ids').splice(1, 1)[0])`

What's the best way to sort elements inside an Immutable data structures with **Immutable.js** ?

Comment: imagine i use this with redux, can't i return a new version of the data structure from a reducer?

Comment: At first I was thinking messing around with `withMutations()`, but really your own function for this would be the best bet. By the way if you think about it, swapping in particular is an awkward series of operations even on plain mutable data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Map.update()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update) and [`List.withMutations()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/withMutations) for that matter:

```
map.update('ids', idsList => idsList.withMutations(function (idsList) {
    let temp = idsList.get(2);
    return idsList.set(2, idsList.get(1)).set(1, temp);
}));
```

Notice that I renamed your `list` to `map` - this is actually a `Map`.

And for simple sorting go for

```
map.update('ids', idsList => idsList.sort(function (a, b) {
    // magic
});
```

Comment: base on your code are these code snippets doing the same ? http://collabshot.com/show/nGarJf

Comment: Nope. You changed  `.update()` to `.set()` and they are not interchangeable, as `set` will simply take second argument and put it in the specified place, while `update` will invoke updater function from second argument and set the returned value. See the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Parametrized:

```
function swap(map, key, from, to) {
    return map.update(key, list => list.withMutations(list => {
        let soruce = list.get(from);
        let destination = list.get(to);
        return list.set(to, soruce).set(from, destination);
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment to swap values at different indexes of array

```
const list = Immutable.fromJS({name:'lolo',ids:[3,4,5]});

[list._root.entries[1][1]._tail.array[1], list._root.entries[1][1]._tail.array[2]] = [
  list._root.entries[1][1]._tail.array[2]
  , list._root.entries[1][1]._tail.array[1]
];

console.log(list.get("ids").toArray());
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcEFNIFTnji3xxs7uTCT?p=preview